# QPainter paints only part of the rectangle over QImage

Tags: c++, qt

I'm loading image into QImage from data in memory, I've managed successfully paint it with QPainter onto QWidget. Then I'm trying to change some pixels of this QImage to highlight rectangle area using rubber band. My problem is that I'm getting only part of the rectangle, and sometimes nothing at all (see picture below).[image: Only one line when it should be four] Code .h:

```
class PaintWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QWidget::QWidget;

    void setSourceSample(Sample src) ;
    void drawRectangle(OCRRectangle rect);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;

private:
    QRectF target=QRectF(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    QImage p_source;
    QPoint origin, end;
    QRubberBand * rubberBand;
    QPair<float, float> rsz_ratio;
    void calcROI();
    QPoint translateCoordinates(cv::Point point);
};
```

Code .cpp:

```
void PaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawImage(target, p_source);
}
void PaintWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
    origin=ev->pos();
    rubberBand=new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
}
void PaintWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, ev->pos()).normalized());
}
void PaintWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
    end=ev->pos();
    rubberBand->hide();
    delete rubberBand;
    calcROI();
}
void PaintWidget::calcROI() {
    int p1x=min(end.x(),origin.x())*rsz_ratio.first;
    int p2x=max(end.x(),origin.x())*rsz_ratio.first;
    int p1y=min(end.y(), origin.y())*rsz_ratio.second;
    int p2y=max(end.y(), origin.y())*rsz_ratio.second;
    drawRectangle(OCRRectangle(cv::Point(p1x, p1y),cv::Point(p2x, p2y)));
}
void PaintWidget::setSourceSample(Sample src) {
    QImage inter=src.toQImage();
    p_source=inter.convertToFormat(QImage::Format::Format_RGB32);
    rsz_ratio.first=(float)src.size().width/(float)(target.width());
    rsz_ratio.second=(float)src.size().height/(float)target.height();
}
QPoint PaintWidget::translateCoordinates(cv::Point point) {
    QPoint qtpoint;
    qtpoint.setX(point.x);
    qtpoint.setY(point.y);
    return qtpoint;
}
void PaintWidget::drawRectangle(OCRRectangle rect) {
    QPoint p1(translateCoordinates(rect.p1)), p2(translateCoordinates(rect.p2));
    for (int i=p1.x(); i<=p2.x(); i++) {
       p_source.setPixelColor(i,p1.y(),QColor(255,0,0));
       p_source.setPixelColor(i, p2.y(), QColor(255,0,0));
    }
    for (int i=p1.y(); i<=p2.y(); i++) {
       p_source.setPixelColor(p1.x(),i,QColor(255,0,0));
       p_source.setPixelColor(p2.x(),i,QColor(255,0,0));
    }
}
```

UPDATE: it seems that the problem lies within rescaling of original image. When I'm drawing filled red rectangle it goes absolutely fine, my guess is that rescaling 1px border rectangle is just erasing borders. But setting thicker borders (up to 5 pixels) doesn't provide me with solution.

Comment: What is `OCRRectangle` class?

Comment: It's custom class, basically it's two openCV points.

Comment: Why do you draw into QImage? You can draw the rectangle in `paintEvent()` instead. Then you always get best quality. If you like, you can transform the QPainters coordinate system into pixel coordinates first as well. Using a pen of size 0 always draws hairline (1px in screen coordinates) which is very convenient for this as well.

Comment: It's because rectangle needed to be drawn upon image loaded from memory.

Comment: @ypnos , thank you, I found a way to draw rectangle over image, it's much better than changing pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Making thicker borders solved this problem.